# how to write rewrite rule to send url parameters

Tags: url-rewriting

I am having a url like below

```
http://www.mywebsite.net/messages/111
```

I need to get the value of 111 either by

```
$_GET['number'] or  $_SERVER['number']
```

I have tried the below ways, but nothing worked for me

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ messages.php?number=$1

#RewriteRule ^messages/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ messages.php?number=$1
#RewriteRule ^messages/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ messages.php?number=$1
```

please kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

this code could help you:

```
<?php
        $number=$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
        $number=str_replace('/','',$number);
        echo ($number);
?>
```